# I2C to UART bridge as breakout or in DIP package

Tags: i2c, uart

For a project, I need to connect more than one device to an Arduino through a serial port with hardware flow control (RTS/CTS).

Sparkfun used to make breakout boards for the [SC16IS750](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9745), but this product is discontinued and I can't find any place to order it. There are also plenty of ICs doing what I need, but I am not keen on soldering SMD components and I cannot find any products coming in e.g. an old fashioned DIP package.

Does someone know about an available breakout board or a DIP packages I2C to UART bridge? Since the device will be battery powered, I would prefer a dedicated low-power circuit instead of a programmed microcontroller as suggested by majenko.

Comment: How about an ATMega328P programmed to do what you want...?

Comment: @Majenko Why didn't I think about that. It would actually work, but since I need the bridge to be always on in a battery-powered device, the power consumption of the ATMega328P is at least disadvantageous. I would prefer a dedicated circuit. I'll edit my question and add the power requirement.

Comment: An ATTiny would reduce the power a little - so would employing sleep modes and wake on I2C or UART interrupts.

Comment: Yes, sleep modes should do it.  Note that hardware flow control is not incompatible with software serial in concept, though there might be a few details to work out.  There may also be dual-UART ATmegas available in large DIP packages.

Comment: You really should invest an hour or two in learning to solder SMD device though - it is not hard at all, and will remove these extreme limitations you face.

Comment: According to what I read, a 'wake on UART activity' concept won't work. After waking up, the ATMega will take some time to resume normal operation and at least the first byte of the UART transmission will be lost. Using such an approach requires control of the transmitter. which must first send a dummy 'wake up byte' on the UART, delay for a short period to wait for the ATMega to run properly and then start the real transmission. Since I cannot change the protocol used by the connected devices, this will not work.

Comment: Less expensive option?
Have no personal experience, but was Googling for a way to add second hardware UART to Arduino Uno. https://www.embeddedadventures.com/i2c_to_uart_mod-1025.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for:

http://sandboxelectronics.com/?product=sc16is750-i2cspi-to-uart-bridge-module

---

From that page:

[image: SC16IS750 I2C/SPI to UART Bridge Module]

> ### SC16IS750 I2C/SPI to UART Bridge Module
>
> This module is designed to enable I2C/SPI to UART conversion. It works in I2C/SPI slave mode and interfaces with devices working in I2C/SPI master mode. There are also 4 extra GPIOs for IO expansion. NXP SC16IS750 is used as the key component on this module. Flow control and modem signals are also supported.
>
> This module is useful when extra UART interface is needed. Due to the multi-slave characteristics of I2C and SPI, many UART interfaces could be added to the system at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelWilkinson Please consider posting a little summary, because your post will be worthless when the source you are linking to changes or is deleted.

Comment: Agreed - links go dead in time. Please summarise your answer so that it stands on its own. At least mention the part number, and maybe post a photo of it.